# How to display a list of Groups from Firebase using an Adapter in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm developing an Android app using Firebase as a database.
In my db there are users and groups.

[Users node of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiSNC.png)

Each user has a list of groups he/she belongs to, each group is stored as groupID.
In another node of the db there is the list of groups, with name, groupImage,... of each group.

[Groups node of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPVUZ.png)

How can i display a list of the group (with name and image) of a user given his userID using a FirebaseListAdapter or whatever?

p.s. the problem is not using the adapter but, after getting the IDs of the groups, accessing them without accessing the whole groups node

Answer (score 0):

You should use a recycle view and an adapter to display all your parameters in a list, here is an Android tutorial to create such a list https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

EDITED:

you can use this function for every group id you got from the user:

```
public void getGroup(String id)
    {
        groupRef.child(id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                 //do something
                 //add data to the list
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
                 //do something
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not using the adapter, but reading data correctly.
I can get the groupIDs putting a listener on user->groups node, but then how can i access the groups without accessing the whole groups node?

Comment: You can add a listener to each of the involving groups ID just like with the users, and then add each group when the event called for them

Comment: Thank you very much! I put a listener in my user->groups node, then inside the OnDataChange, i do something like
for (every groupID) do getGroup(groupID);
getGroup listens for that group and adds a Group object to a HashMap.
But in which point of the code do i print the list? I can't print it after the "for" cycle because i still don't have data in my HashMap here (data are read asynchronously)

Comment: In the get group id function, you should check if this is the last group id to be added and then print the list. You can achieve this by checking if the hashmap size reached the wanted count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this using the database structure that i see in those screenshots, you need to iterate twice. First off all you need to find all groups in which the user is subscribed. This means you need to find the group ids from the `users` node. Than you need to iterate again, to find the group names, based on the corresponding group id. And after this to display the list of the group names that you need.

The simplest way to achieve this is to change the `group id` with the `group name`. This means that, in stead of iterating twice, you'll need to iterate only once. Your database structure should look like this:

```
user
 |
 --- // stuff
 |
 --- groups
       |
       --- group_1: true
       |
       --- group_2: true
       |
       --- group_3: true
       |
       --- group_4: true
       |
       --- group_5: true+
       |
       --- // other stuff
```

This means you can iterate over: `users/groups` and actually get the name of the groups that a single user has subscribed. These are the group names that you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is everything alright? Can i help you with other informations?